# Invertible matrix theorem

Tags: matrices, inverse

I learned invertible matrix theorem, and I want to know the relation of this two statements.

> (k) There is an $m\times n$ matrix $D$ such that $AD=I$
>
> (g) The equation $Ax=b$ has at least one solution for each b in
>   $\Bbb{R}^n$

Book says (k) implies (g) but there is no proof so I want to prove this. Statement (g) is the definition of "onto", however I cannot prove this. How can I derive (g) from (k)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you simply need the associativity of matrix multiplication. Then, if you take $x=Db$ you have $A(Db)=(AD)b=Ib=b$

The intuition here is that if $Ax=b$ then "$x=A^{-1}b$" - you don't necessarily have an inverse, but $D$ has the property of the inverse that you do need, and will do in place of $A^{-1}$.

Comment: What you mean is that in the $Ax=b$, there is at least one solution $x=Db$?

Comment: @baeharam Yes, that is a solution. There may be others ($D$ is not necessarily unique if $m\neq n$, for example, but at least one $D$ is given)